# Returning a certain pattern for animations using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval

I'm learning JavaScript and intended to animate divs over an image to get the effect of "curtains closing" over that image. But I would like to do that in a specific endless way (one after the other till it starts all over again) since 9 images should be displayed inside a "matrix/grid" 3*3. After some research I've decided to try the setInterval method since, as far as I'm concerned, it keeps calling a function given a certain interval. Somehow, I don't know why, I can't get this effect, and the animation stucks after the first execution!

```js
function Live(cont) {
  if (cont == 1) {
    return [
      (document.getElementById("curtain-1").style.animation = "t-enclosure 1.5s"), (document.getElementById("curtain-2").style.animation = "b-enclosure 1.5s "),
    ];
  } else if (cont == 2) {
    return [
      (document.getElementById("curtain-3").style.animation = "t-enclosure 1.5s"), (document.getElementById("curtain-4").style.animation = "b-enclosure 1.5s "),
    ];
  }

setInterval(Live(1), 1000);

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

<script>
  setInterval(Live(1), 1000);
  setInterval(Live(2), 2000); 
</script>

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

```css
#section {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
}

@keyframes t-enclosure {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: aqua;
  }
  100% {
    height: 180px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: aqua;
  }
}

@keyframes b-enclosure {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: aliceblue;
  }
  100% {
    height: 60px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: aliceblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="frame-gallery">
  <img id="section" src="./img/dolphins.jpg" alt="">
  <div id="curtain-1" class="t-frame-gallery"></div>
  <div id="curtain-2" class="b-frame-gallery"></div>
</div>

<div id="sec" class="frame-gallery">
  <img id="section" src="./img/butterfly.jpg" alt="">
  <div id="curtain-3" class="t-frame-gallery"></div>
  <div id="curtain-4" class="b-frame-gallery"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: a few hints to push you into the right direction: This is not a JS task as it can be purely done with CSS. You should trigger the animation with a CSS class. If you want to do it with JS then you should not use the `.style` function in 2023 anymore. It only has very limited good use. The modern approach is to use the `.classList` function to add, remove, or toggle CSS classes on an element (which again would solve it with CSS).

Comment: PS: After reading your description multiple times I still don't get what effect you want to achieve. I also don't get what your JS code intends to achieve. Are those multiple JS files or is it a script somewhere else that should influence the JS file?

Comment: There are multiple files. The lógic: (e.g. first animate img1, then img5, then img3, then img7, then img9, then img2 and so on until img1 animates again). Here we have only 2 imgs.
Given 9 images:

img1| img2| img3
img4| img5| img6
img7| img8| img9

Both t-enclosure and b-enclosure grow from top to bottom and bottom to top, respectively, gaining color and opacity (0.5) since these divs have no height until the animation starts (vertical curtains that would cover the image lol). 
Any suggestions on how to achieve this effect would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why not simply apply the "curtains" through pseudo-elements on the container? Then you only need 2 curtains which and no timing in JS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Basically, the question was "how to delay an animation?". I finally did it by using @keyframes and some math. Thank you.